Finding hostname and port of db2 database connection in JAVA
In Java while making database connection we are constructing dburl using configured db2 hostname and port from properties file and then assigning alternate servers(clientRerouteAlternateServerName) and alternate ports(clientRerouteAlternatePortNumber) to db2 connection properties. So even when primary db2 host is down connection is established to one of these servers defined in alternate servers. How can i determine to which host and port connection got established using connection object.
Please help with any suggestions !

It's unclear to me why you would not know that

The Connection object can provide the DatabaseMetaData object that includes the URL you want. See DatabaseMetaData.getURL().

@g00se I am looking for a way to determine how to find that information.

You have the source code?

Does your question concern only the Db2 for linux/unix/windows platform? You should always write the platform in your question.

You might not have off-the-shelf solutions with currently shipping versions...but you could grow your own.
Db2-LUW Database discovery is not a mandatory characteristic of a database - IBM made discovery optional for a Db2-LUW database.
There is a 'c' language API to search the system/local database directory (db2DbDirOpenScan and related functions). It is not remotized and lacks a java interface. For on-premises Db2-LUW instances, you could create a server-based process (i.e. where the database-directory will always exist as long as at least one database exists) that exported a remotized interface for java subject to local security policies.
The Db2 DAS offered discovery features for participating databases but DAS is deprecated and did not have a java API.
Mainframe Db2(z/os) has different solutions, as does i-series.
The information you seek is perhaps best treated as configuration inputs.

Hostname of the server you are connected to can be determined in DB2 LUW as follows.
SELECT HOME_HOST 
FROM SYSIBMADM.DB2_MEMBER
WHERE ID = CURRENT MEMBER

No port info is available.
